# jQuery scroll effect not working

Tags: jquery, scroll

I've tried to implement [this](http://www.sycha.com/jquery-smooth-scrolling-internal-anchor-links) on my site but it simply does not work. Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

[Site with jQuery code included but nothing happening](http://www.haselden.co.uk/james/docs/index.html)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined ` fix your JavaScript errors.

Comment: Javascript on your site is incorrect. You need to implement it *exactly* as shown in the example.

Comment: The jQuery was taken from the site that seems to work fine for everyone else, and the actual jQuery file was from the jQuery site itself... I'm not sure how to fix errors in code that should be fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code provided by the smooth scrolling tutorial:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    });
});
```

This is the code on your page:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('[name="'+this.hash.substring(1)+'"]').offset().top}, 500);
```

The code you are using is the alternative the tutorial provides when using named anchors. However, that is meant the replace the corresponding part of the original code. I believe what you should have is this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('[name="'+this.hash.substring(1)+'"]').offset().top}, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: I see what you mean, I did not pay attention and just put the alt code in and thought that would work. Thanks for pointing that out to me. However, the new code you've presented doesn't work either.

Comment: Change `<a href="#whoami">Who am I?</a>` to `<a href="#whoami" class="scroll">Who am I?</a>` and it should work.
And do the same for **all** links with hashes.

Comment: You will need to a scroll class to the anchor that you would like to perform the scrolling, most likely the <a href="#portfolioAnchor">​

Comment: @zysoft Thank you!! I was putting the class of scroll on the target anchor instead of the target link! Thanks a lot, I was completely bemused as I couldn't see the error in front of me. D'oh. Thanks a lot for your help.